# How to Add Padding to Vertical Dropdown without Messing up Dropdown?

Tags: html, css

I want my vertical drop-down menus' parent tabs to have padding *and* the children tabs to be in the correct position.

You see, if I don't have any padding around the parent tabs ([here](https://jsfiddle.net/hexnxo7n/)), it looks like this:
[image]

If I have padding around the parent tabs ([here](https://jsfiddle.net/u1ssgvy9/)), it messes up the entire dropdown and it looks like this:

[image]

What I would like the dropdown to do is have BOTH padding around the parent tabs (like the second image) AND the normal dropdown (like the first). How do I prevent this strange padding around the entire dropdown when I add padding around the parent tabs? Is there another way of adding space around the parent tabs that doesn't cause this problem?  I understand negative padding/margins could potentially work, but is there a better solution?

Example of an ideal header (photoshopped, not screenshot):
[image]

Here is the difference:

```
ul li {padding: 10px;}
```

Without the ul li padding, it looks like image 1. With it, it looks like image 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Grace Sawyer, it's an issue of specificity. When you implement your code `ul li { padding 10px; }` that styling is being inherited by the list-items in your sub-menu. One way of overcoming this is to add selecting those submenu list-items and setting their styling directly. This way it overrides the inherited styling. If you need a refresher or are new to CSS, this is a good article that I always refer back to for referencing [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

If you add these lines of code to your CSS, you'll get your desired results

```
nav ul li { padding: 15px; }

nav ul li ul li { padding: 0px;}
```

I also forked your jsfiddle and implemented the code, so you can see it in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dn36rtxf/).

Comment: Great!  If I replace it with padding, it would look more like how I would like it to be: https://jsfiddle.net/dn36rtxf/2/. Thanks.

Comment: You got it! Good luck.